# How do I use a value from component to another component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mern

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hj2BQ.jpg)

How do I use a <h1>{taille}</h1> from component to another component

How do I use a <h1>{taille}</h1> from component to another component

```
import "./SizeShirt.css"
import React,{useState} from "react"


const SizeShirt = () => {
  const[taille,setTaille]=useState()

  return (
    <>
        <h1>{taille}</h1>
        <input type="radio" className="btn-check" name="options" id="option1" autocomplete="off" value="S" onChange={e=>setTaille(e.target.value)} />
        <label className="btn btn-primary" htmlFor="option1">S</label>

        <input type="radio" className="btn-check" name="options" id="option2" autocomplete="off" value="M" onChange={e=>setTaille(e.target.value)} />
        <label className="btn btn-primary ms-2" htmlFor="option2">M</label>

        <input type="radio" className="btn-check" name="options" id="option3" autocomplete="off" value="L"  onChange={e=>setTaille(e.target.value)}/>
        <label className="btn btn-primary ms-2" htmlFor="option3">L</label>

        <input type="radio" className="btn-check" name="options" id="option4" autocomplete="off" value="XL" onChange={e=>setTaille(e.target.value)} />
        <label className="btn btn-primary ms-2" htmlFor="option4">XL</label>
    </>

)
}

export default SizeShirt
```

Comment: What does "use a <h1>{taille}</h1> from component to another component" mean? Please elaborate on what you are trying to do.

Comment: https://react.dev/learn/sharing-state-between-components

Answer (score 0):

am just give you a simple example with three component that will help you to understand the sharing of data between these three-

First Component (component have some data)-

```
import {useState} from 'react'
import SecondComponent from './SecondComponent'
import ThirdComponent from './ThirdComponent'

const FirstComponent = ()=>{
const [data,setData] = useState('Sample Data')
return(
<>
<SecondComponent data={data} setData={setData} />
<ThirdComponent data={data} setData={setData} />
<>
)
}
```

in the SecondComponent, basically accept values from the first and sets new data in the first state-

```
const SecondComponent = ({data,setData})=>{
return(
<>
<span>{data &&data}</span>
<button onClick={()=>setData('Hello data from second')}>Click on Second Component</button/>
</>
)
}

export const SecondComponent
```

same in the third component-

```
const ThirdComponent = ({data,setData})=>{
return(
<>
<span>{data &&data}</span>
<button onClick={()=>setData('Hey data from Third')}>Click on Second Component</button/>
</>
)
}

export const ThirdComponent
```

So you just need to useState in the parent to handle the state for more than two components, also you can use ContextAPI, local storage and redux to manage the state..
if you still facing issue just lemme know I will help you more..